# Using a page variable as an if statements conditon within a control

Tags: silverstripe

I have the following problem:
I have the variable `$GiftID` on my page. 
I want to cycle through all of my gift objects using my function `getGifts()`. 
When the `$ID` of the gift is equal to the `$GiftID` of the page then I want something to happen.

Here is an example of my code:

```
$GiftID 
<% control getGifts %> 
   <% if CurrentPage.GiftID = ID %>This is it!<% end_if %> 
<% end_control %>
```

Using `$CurrentPage.GiftID` works when printing inside the control, but how on earth do I access it from within the if statement?

I am using SS 2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used ss2.9 yet, but as far as I know you can not do `<% if Top.GiftID = ID %>` in any 2.x version, you can not compare 2 variables, you can only compare with static vaules. (but it is possible in 3.0)

So you have to do it on php side, if you want to only display the slected gift object, then:

1. if `GiftID` is actually the DB field for the has_one relation of `Gift` then you can just do <% control Gift %> and it will scope the Gift object with the GiftID
2. If you really have `GiftID` saved as DB field or otherwise, then can do
   `public function getGift() { return DataObject::get_by_id('Gift', $this->GiftID); }`

both ways you can do <% control Gift %> and it will scope it

If you want to list all gifts and mark the current gift then you need to do it on php side (foreach the set of objects and set a flag on the current object)

Comment: Marked as best answer for confirming that you can cannot compare 2 variables. I figured this out the long way by viewing the generated php and discovering it was actually comparing the second variable name as if it was a string. Thanks for your suggestions to solve my issue - What I was trying to do was generate a select list with a preselected item, depending on the post variables. I ended up creating a method which generated this html for me in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the current page with `Top`:

```
<% control getGifts %> 
   <% if Top.GiftID = ID %>This is it!<% end_if %> 
<% end_control %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Though SS doesn't seem to allow any variables with a . in the variable name in an if statement. Any time I try CurrentPage.GiftID or Parent.GiftID or Top.GiftID I just get a white screen of death.

Comment: In my apache error logs I get a
**PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}'**
This is only when I have `if Top.GiftID = ID` but the statement throws no errors when it is just `if Top.GiftID`

Comment: Just discovered that you can add showtemplate=1 to your query string and it will show you the PHP code generated by the code. It seems that ss only allows you to compare a variable to a string, so if I try and compare the ID and the Price variables of the object: `if ID = Price` then it converts to the php equivalent of `if ($ID == "Price")`. I guess I am going to have to come up with some other ugly solution for this, such as generating my html in my controller and retrieving it with a variable where I had my control. Yuck.

Comment: You are going to need to write a custom method either on your Page class or your Gift class. Provide more code, and we'll give you an example of how to do it. For example, where does CurrentPage come from? And how are you generating $GiftID?

Comment: Thanks for the help - What I was trying to do was generate a select list with a preselected item, depending on the post variables. I ended up creating a method which generated this html for me in my controller.